# Control iPhone volume using phonegap?

Tags: iphone, cordova

I was wondering if anyone knew how to control the iPhone's volume using PhoneGap/Titanium/Corona? If not I would very much appreciate a tutorial on how to develop my own plugin that would be able to interface with the iPhone frameworks and develop something along the lines of MPVolumeView.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Dredging up an old question, but there is a plugin available for this now if anyone stumbles upon this question looking for a solution:

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/VolumeSlider

It basically does exactly what @Aaron Saunders suggested (loads an MPVolumeView via a plugin).